# making an unbound listview i.e. set alarm screen in the alarm clock app

Tags: android, listview

Well like the title says if you go to the Alarm clock App on droid i am trying to recreate the screen that comes up when you select an alarm. Essentially the "other" screen in the app. I am new to this but have spent the past day searching for this but im not to sure i know the correct terminology to find what im looking for.

I am making a time clock app that keeps track of my hours at work. 
I want to make a 3 row listview 
1st row: a title RightOfthat EditText RightOfthat Button. 
2nd row: a title RightOfthat EditText RightOfthat Button. 
3rd row a title RightOfthat EditText. 
But i want it to look just like the screen on the Alarm Clock app.

i figured out how to format and bound listview using SQLite anyway i want but i am having trouble using listview with out bound data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can u please provide a snippet of what you are trying to do??

Comment: Sorry i am a self taught programmer and am terminology illiterate. Do you want me to provide my code?